# How to override "env_file" during tests?

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, pydantic

I'm reading env variables from `.prod.env` file in my *config.py*:

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    A: int

    class Config:
        env_file = ".prod.env"
        env_file_encoding = "utf-8"

settings = Settings()
```

in my *main.py* I'm creating the `app` like so:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.config import settings

app = FastAPI()
print(settings.A)
```

I am able to override settings variables like this in my `conftest.py`:

```py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app.main import app
from app.config import settings

settings.A = 42

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_clinet():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client
```

This works fine, whenever I use `settings.A` I get 42.

But is it possible to override the whole `env_file` from `.prod.env` to another env file `.test.env`?

Also I probably want to call `settings.A = 42` in *conftest.py* before I import `app`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the env file you use by creating a `Settings` instance with the `_env_file` keyword argument.

From [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/):

> Passing a file path via the `_env_file` keyword argument on instantiation (method 2) will override the value (if any) set on the `Config` class. If the above snippets were used in conjunction, prod.env would be loaded while .env would be ignored.

For example, this *should* work for your test -

```
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

import app.config as conf
from app.config import Settings

# replace the settings object that you created in the module
conf.settings = Settings(_env_file='.test.env')

from app.main import app

# just to show you that you changed the module-level
# settings
from app.config import settings

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_client():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client

def test_settings():
    print(conf.settings)
    print(settings)
```

And you could create a `.test.env`, set `A=10000000`, and run with

```
pytest -rP conftest.py

# stuff
----- Captured stdout call -----
A=10000000
A=10000000
```

This looks a little messy (though this is probably only used for test purposes), so I'd recommend not creating a `settings` object that is importable by everything in your code, and instead making it something you create in, say, your `__main__` that actually creates and runs the app, but that's a design choice for you to make.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today, really annoying. My goal was to set a different postgresql database for the unit tests. The default configuration comes from a `.env` file. But when you think of it thoroughly it is not that difficult to understand. It all boils down to the order of the imported modules in `conftest.py`. I based the example below on the answer of @wkl:

```
import pytest

from typing import Generator
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

import app.core.config as config
from app.core.config import Settings

# Replace individual attribute in the settings object
config.settings = Settings(
    POSTGRES_DB="test_db")

# Or replace the env file in the settings object
config.settings = Settings(_env_file='.test.env')

# All other modules that import settings are imported here
# This ensures that those modules will use the updated settings object
# Don't forget to use "noqa", otherwise a formatter might put it back on top
from app.main import app  # noqa
from app.db.session import SessionLocal  # noqa


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def client() -> Generator:
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c
```

Answer (score -1):

One workaround I have found is to remove the `env_file` from Config completely and replace it's functionality with `load_dotenv()` from dotenv like this:

*config.py*:

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(".prod.env")


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    A: int


settings = Settings()
```

*conftest.py*:

```py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("test.env")

from app.config import settings
from app.main import app


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_clinet():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client
```

Please note, that calling `load_dotenv("test.env")` happens before importing the settings (`from app.config import settings`)

and also note that load_dotenv() will load environment variables globally for the whole python script.

Loading env variables like this will not override already exported variables, same as using the `env_file` in pydantic's BaseSettings